# map of string within a map object

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-compute-engine

I'm trying to create a Compute Engine instance and I'm trying to map values of different types, but I'm getting error as you can see from the following code.

```
variable "compute_engine_instances" {
  type = map(object({
    instance_name = string
    machine_type  = string
    zone          = string
    tags          = list(string)
    image_name    = string
    image_project = string
    labels        =list(object({
    app_id      = number
    cost_center = string
    owner       = string
    email       = string
  }))
  }))
}

module "compute_engines" {
  source = "../modules/compute_engine"

  for_each      = var.compute_engine_instances
  project_id    = var.project_id
  instance_name = each.value.instance_name
  machine_type  = each.value.machine_type
  tags          = each.value.tags
  labels        = each.value.labels
  subnetwork    = var.subnetwork
  zone          = each.value.zone
  image_name    = each.value.image_name
  image_project = each.value.image_project
}
```

Terraform tf vars file as:

```
compute_engine_instances ={
    "test-adi"={

    instance_name = "test-vm"
    machine_type  = "n1-standard-1"
    zone           = "us-east4-b"
    tags   = ["foo","bar"]
    image_name    = "centos-7"
    image_project = "cc-devtools"
    labels = [{
  app_id      = "6"
  cost_center = "0156"
  owner       = "ops"
  email       = "ps"
}]
}
}
```

I'm getting the following error when I run tf plan, How can i fix this error?

Thanks for you help.

```
Error: Incorrect attribute value type

  on ..\modules\compute_engine\main.tf line 14, in resource "google_compute_instance" "generic_instance":
  14:   labels = var.labels

Inappropriate value for attribute "labels": map of string required.
```

modules folder looks like the following:

```
data "google_compute_image" "compute_image" {
  name    = var.image_name
  project = var.image_project
}

resource "google_compute_instance" "generic_instance" {
  project      = var.project_id
  name         = var.instance_name
  machine_type = var.machine_type
  zone         = var.zone

  tags   = var.tags
  labels = var.labels

  boot_disk {
    initialize_params {
      image = data.google_compute_image.compute_image.self_link
    }
    auto_delete = true
  }

  network_interface {
    subnetwork = var.subnetwork
  }
}
```

labels variable in modules is as follows:

```
variable "labels" {
  type        = any
  description = "A list of labels for this VM"
}
```

Comment: What is `labels` in your module?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check tf docs, [labels](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/compute_instance#labels), it should be a **map** (not list like in your case) of key/value label pairs:

```
variable "compute_engine_instances" {
  type = map(object({
    instance_name = string
    machine_type  = string
    zone          = string
    tags          = list(string)
    image_name    = string
    image_project = string
    labels        =object({
    app_id      = number
    cost_center = string
    owner       = string
    email       = string
  })
  }))
}


compute_engine_instances ={
    "test-adi"={

    instance_name = "test-vm"
    machine_type  = "n1-standard-1"
    zone           = "us-east4-b"
    tags   = ["foo","bar"]
    image_name    = "centos-7"
    image_project = "cc-devtools"
    labels = {
  app_id      = "6"
  cost_center = "0156"
  owner       = "ops"
  email       = "ps"
}
}
}
```